# Uninstall kubuntu-desktop error

Tags: apt

I installed KDE and now I want to remove it. Using the following command: `sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop`

But instead of removing it, I get the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

After running the `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
 I tried again to run the purge command and this was the output:

```
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I ran the `apt-get -f install` with no packages but that didn't fix the issue. The output of this  command is:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 364670 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you run the command "sudo dpkg --configure  -a"? Is yes then what was the output.

Comment: I edited the question with the output.

Comment: I recommend you to use KDE Neon, it´s a kde official distro based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I used Synaptic and uninstalled kubuntu. I used "Mark for Complete Removal" on the kubuntu packages and that solved the problem.

I also installed BleachBit and did an autoclean to remove unnecessary obsolete files.

Answer (score 0):

You must have interupted dpkg. Just run the command it says and everything should be fixed and you can remove it.

Comment: Already did it. I edited the question with the output I get.

Comment: Can you remove kde-config-telepathy-accounts then xubuntu?

Comment: I can't remove kde-config-telepathy-accounts. Same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i

rm /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get update

apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'

aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kde),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'

apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

deborphan

apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)

deborphan --libdevel

apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)

deborphan --find-config

dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)

apt-get autoremove

apt-get clean

reboot
```